# Swiftmailer call to undefined method setPassword()

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have no idea why Swiftmailer is giving me an error.

Fatal error Call to undefined method setPassowrd in.. lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php

I have checked the file and it does not contain the method. Though I am following the correct documentation for it, found below.
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-smtp-transport

My code is as is:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')->setUsername('myUserName@gmail.com')->setPassowrd('myPassword');
//$transport->setLocalDomain('[127.0.0.1]');
//The above has been tried with and with out.
$theMessage = Swift_Message::newInstance();

$to = 'toEmail@example.com';
$theMessage->setTo(array($to => 'aName');

$theMessage->setSubject = 'Contact Form';
$theMessage->setBody = $body;
$theMessage->setFrom(array($email => $name));

$theMessage->WordWrap = 50;

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->send($theMessage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is called `setPassword()`, not `setPassowrd()`. You spelt it incorrectly.

[Source](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php#L110).

[Documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html).

Comment: Wow... That was rather embarrassing. Thanks. I've been staring at it but didn't bother to double check the method.

Comment: @pmac89 These things happen to everyone :)

Comment: Also the method you seek is inside `Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler` which is invoked through the magic `_call` method on `Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport`.

Comment: Ah... I saw it in the AuthHandler. I didn't know it was invoked through the _call, I only read through it slightly. Though I only know a little about OOP with PHP. Lastly, I hate getting tunnel vision.